# Semantic UI cards height issue (chrome on windows)

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, semantic-ui

I'm having an issue on chrome for windows where my `.card` items don't seem to get the right height. They get too much or too little resulting in the issue you can see in my screenshot below. This is only happening on Chrome for Windows as far as I can tell.

Platforms where this issue doesn't happen:

- Internet Explorer 11
- Microsoft Edge
- Firefox
- Chrome on mac

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp72ez4h/)

[image: Screenshot of my application]

```
<div class="ui grid stackable container">
  <div class="sixteen wide column">
    <div class="ui link five doubling cards">
      <a class="ui card" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://assets19.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//002.png">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="header">Ivysaur</div>
          <div class="meta">Grass</div>
          <div class="description">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
          <span><i class="idea icon"></i>Pokemon</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="ui card" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://assets19.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//004.png">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="header">Charmander</div>
          <div class="meta">Fire</div>
          <div class="description">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
          <span><i class="idea icon"></i>Pokemon</span>
        </div>
      </a>

      ...

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you add this to a Fiddle. There is no scss/css to debug here.

Comment: @JamiePaterson added

Comment: Everything looks the same here. Tested on Chrome for Windows, and it's the same as FF, IE11, etc.

Comment: @Michael_B it seems to be some sort of chrome bug, that's not easy to reproduce. I'll look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in production on one of [my website](https://the-cluster.org/). The bug appears if the images are not in cache and must be downloaded, only on Chrome, after a recent update.

I found that a commit was about the css-flex used by semantic-ui to produce cards. This [bug report](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6841) details the problem and some workarounds.
I chose to add `min-height: 0;` to the content of my card and It worked the way it should.